# How to optimize curl request structure

Tags: php, curl

I have a working function that does the following.

1.) Request the list of items from a webpage.
2.) Loops through obtained list of items and assembles an array containing the information of each item in list.

The current structure of the loop is as follows:

```
foreach($list as $key=>$value) {

    $url =  'http://www.example.com?item_number=' . $value;

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    if(curl_exec($ch) === false){               

    curl_close($ch);
    unset($ch);

    } else{

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch); 
        unset($ch);

        $item_details[] = $response;

        unset($response);           

        }



}
```

The problem I am running into is that this list can contain hundreds of items. Each item making an independent request to the example site.  This times out my script via the FcgidIOTimeout in the mod_fcgid. This setting appears to be set at 120 secs.

I am running this script from the cron manager using a godaddy shared hosting account. I do not have the ability to change the FcgidIOTimeout settings via any ini_set() functions or through htaccess.  My max_execution_time and max_input time are set much higher than 120 secs.

set_time_limit() does not seem to work as desired by extending the run time through the loop.

This is the error that I am receiving from the server error logs.

```
[warn] [client ] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 120 seconds
[error] [client ] Premature end of script headers:
```

My main question are:
1. Can this be done as to minimized the number of handshakes to the example server through a single request.
2. Can I force the script to delay the headers or to force headers to be sent to avoid the error.

I have read that I could use a console script to run this inside of the shell, and that may solve the issue, but I will be honest in saying I would not have any idea on how to create or trigger a console script to run this code.

Thank you in advance.

----My solution---------

I found in the php documentation the curl_multi_exec.  I turned their example into a function where you pass an array of url's and how many threads you want to operate.  I am sure that you could also pass the curl_opts as an array also.  Someone with more knowledge than I could even write a class for it, but none the less this is my result.  It did perform my task in 20 seconds vs timing out at 120 secs.  Thanks for your feedback.

Regards

```
function multi_thread_curl($url_array, $number_threads) {


 $curl_array = array_chunk($url_array, $number_threads, $preserve_keys = true);

//Iterate through each batch of urls.
foreach($curl_array as $threads) {

    //Create your cURL resources.
    foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

    ${ch . $key} = curl_init();

    curl_setopt(${ch . $key}, CURLOPT_URL, $value);
    curl_setopt(${ch . $key}, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);  
    curl_setopt(${ch . $key}, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt(${ch . $key}, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);

    }


    //Create the multiple cURL handler.
    $mh = curl_multi_init();

    //Add the handles.
    foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, ${ch . $key});

    }

    $active = null;

    //execute the handles.
    do {

    $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

    } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);

    while ($active && $mrc == CURLM_OK) {

        if (curl_multi_select($mh) != -1) {
            do {

                $mrc = curl_multi_exec($mh, $active);

            } while ($mrc == CURLM_CALL_MULTI_PERFORM);
        }

    }

    //Get your data and close the handles.
    foreach($threads as $key=>$value) {

    $results[$key] = curl_multi_getcontent(${ch . $key});

    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, ${ch . $key});

    }

    //Close the multi handle exec.
    curl_multi_close($mh);

}


return $results;

unset($results);

}
```

Comment: Maybe the site has another API function where you can supply a list of items, and it returns all the results at once.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not an option.

Comment: is it possible to pass an array of item numbers? something like `$url = 'http://www.example.com?item_number[]=' . implode('&item_number[]=',$list);`

Comment: I gave that a try and it did not work.